# Appending JSON content to a JSON file in WSO2

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-integration-studio

I have few JSON Payloads that have to be appended to a JSON file.
This is how my JSON Payload will look:

```
{"variant": {"940894": {"attributes": {"Size": "XL" } } } }
```

I will be getting multiple json Payloads of this type.
At the end I need to form a file that looks like this:

```
[
{"variant": {"940894": {"attributes": {"Size": "XL" } } } },
{"variant": {"940895": {"attributes": {"Size": "Med"    } } } },
{"variant": {"940895": {"attributes": {"Size": "Small"  } } } }
]
```

These are the properties I have set for the requirement:

```
<property expression="fn:concat('Test',get-property('File_Name'),'.txt')" name="FILE_NAME" scope="default"
<propertyGroup description="File and OutputPayload properties">
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
        <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:FILE_NAME" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    </propertyGroup>       
            <call>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="vfs:sftp://username:password/home/user/test/out/json?transport.vfs.Append=true">
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                </markForSuspension>
            </address>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
```

But I get an error saying "The file type does not support append mode". What else can I try here.

Comment: This means the file system doesn't support appending files. May be read the file append the content and replace the file?

Comment: But it gives the same error for every kind of file. I've tried csv, xml, txt, json.

Comment: It works only in local file system. but not in SFTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the code, and as you already noticed `SFTP` protocol doesn't allow you to do file appending. The supported operations for `SFTP` are [here](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-commons-vfs/blob/64054b8de86f7ba5882412c4513dbd50c9248530/commons-vfs2/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/sftp/SftpFileProvider.java#L48) in the code.

```
Capability.CREATE, Capability.DELETE, Capability.RENAME, Capability.GET_TYPE,
Capability.LIST_CHILDREN, Capability.READ_CONTENT, Capability.URI, Capability.WRITE_CONTENT,
Capability.GET_LAST_MODIFIED, Capability.SET_LAST_MODIFIED_FILE, Capability.RANDOM_ACCESS_READ
```

But if you use `FTP` protocol instead you should be able to do File Appending as it's supported [here](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-commons-vfs/blob/64054b8de86f7ba5882412c4513dbd50c9248530/commons-vfs2/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/ftp/FtpFileProvider.java#L44).

```
Capability.CREATE, Capability.DELETE, Capability.RENAME,
Capability.GET_TYPE, Capability.LIST_CHILDREN,
Capability.READ_CONTENT, Capability.GET_LAST_MODIFIED,
Capability.URI, Capability.WRITE_CONTENT,
Capability.APPEND_CONTENT, Capability.RANDOM_ACCESS_READ
```

Appending works with the Local file system too.

If you want to append the file and still use `SFTP` you will have to READ -> APPEND -> WRITE the file. Or can consider writing a Custom Class mediator.